# Can RAFT as a protocol support only leader election?

Tags: distributed-system, raft

I need to execute certain jobs in regular intervals (say every min). If a single node does this, we have a single point of failure. To avoid this, I was thinking of following scheme:

```
1. Nodes form a raft cluster, with leader election
2. Only the leader executes scheduled jobs
     2.1. Every node checks if it is the leader before executing jobs.
3. Replication of commands is not required, thus we would not have a replicated log
```

In order to achieve this only leader election is necessary. So is it possible that I only implement the leader election part of RAFT and achieve this? Are there are any problems with this approach?

**Update 1**
The following was wrong assumption: (This cant happen)

<del>*One issue I can see is: The possibility of two leaders in the case of network partition. But this something I am thinking I can ignore.*</del>

Update 2:
It is not required to restart failed jobs

Note: I could possibly use Zookeeper or something similar to achieve this, but my aim is to write my own

Comment: How can you have two leaders? You need a full quorum to elect the leader

Comment: What happens if the leader fails during a job? If you want the job re-run then things get a lot more complicated.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was wrong about two leaders, but lets say we do not consider job failure, it should be OK right?

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff can you please add your answer, instead of comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a log is not necessary. The leader-follower-candidate state machine and timeouts are enough for a host to know its the leader. (Try it out here https://raft.github.io/ !)

However, be aware that there is a short period of time when a leader doesn't realize that it's lost its leadership due to, say, a network partition.

There are two ways to handle this.

**A**. A leader can only act within a safety window after it's last confirmation from the quorum of heartbeats. **This has problems, as shown in the update.**

Recall that there is a parameter called the *election_timeout* and another unamed parameter I'll call *hearbeat_timeout*. A leader should never do work after *election_timeout* has passed since it has received it's last quorum of updates MINUS some time for the packet to travel across the network.

```
|<- hearbeat_timeout ->|
|<---------------- election_timeout ------------------>|
                                   |<- safety_margin ->|
|<----- safe_time_to_do_work ----->|
```

**B**. When a leader is newly elected, it should wait some time before acting as a leader.

```
|<----------------- election_timeout ----------------->|
|<- hearbeat_timeout ->|
|<---- safety_margin ---->|
                          |<-- safe_time_to_do_work -->|
```

---

You'll want to log who is the leader at a given time though; in an application log or in raft itself.

If you *do* end up using the raft log be sure each leader commits *something*, even if it's just a string "host XYZ is leader now" because raft sometimes requires the [log to move forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416155/4931) to commit previous values.

---

**Update**: There is some important subtlety to all this. There is a case where an out-of-date host can very easily depose a leader.

Consider the case where a host doesn't receive a few heartbeats. It's election timer runs out and it broadcasts itself as a new candidate for a new generation. **This can happen at any time and nullifies the *A*'s safety-margins above.** There is nothing in raft to prevent this, which I have long thought as a shortcoming in raft.

If you want to keep scheme *A* you can amend the protocol so that followers will reject election requests that have come within their heartbeat. You'll also have to make sure the leader relinquishes control at some point. This will significantly slow down failover.

Comment: Won't using heartbeat be enough to know who is the current leader? When the leader sends it's heartbeat it includes it's id. And this can be held in memory by followers?

Answer (score 1):

Leader election requires a log [the first thing a leader does is write a new log entry] and some other bookkeeping persistent state, so you'll need a log even if you're not replicating any commands. You wouldn't need a very performant log or transport, but otherwise i think you're going to be writing most of what's described in the raft paper.

I'd recommend looking for a library or using an existing service such as ZooKeeper or etcd for coordination, having said that, if your system can cope with the job being run concurrently [as would be the case in the partition you indicate you can ignore], then you can save yourself a lot of work, and just always run it on a number of hosts.